# Problems with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.8.0.

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.learn"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What should I write?

Answer (score 1):

Your ads library uses version `11.8.0`, so you should update all the Google dependencies to the same version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.8'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.8'
```

Comment: Now it shows me: 
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.8(Error 29, 13)                   
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.8(Error 34, 13)                            
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.8

Comment: Check this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup